# How to resize image on client-side before upload?

Tags: php, javascript, images, uploads

I've been using Plupload to resize images on the client side before uploading them to the server. I've implemented a front-end form which lets the user select a file from their computer and submit it. My Plupload config looks like this:

```
var uploader = new plupload.Uploader({
  browse_button: 'browse',
  url: $url,
  resize: {
    width: 100,
    height: 100
  }
});
```

I'm now using the [Simple Local Avatars](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-local-avatars/) plugin to let users upload an avatar. Basically, an avatar upload field gets added to user profiles. [wp_handle_upload()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_handle_upload) is used to handle the upload. Is there any way I can resize the image before it's uploaded to the server (similar to how Plupload does)?

Ref: http://www.plupload.com/docs/Image-Resizing-on-Client-Side

Comment: More complex progress, but see this post http://www.krishnakantsharma.com/image-uploads-on-wordpress-admin-screens-using-jquery-and-new-plupload/#.VJM1A9-Fpc8

Comment: Ask to the developer if he/she will use plupload or any other upload plugin that you configure at your own. And, by the way, third party plugins is off-topic here. It is imposible to study the code of each plugin out there to see how they are doing things.