# How to resize an image server-side before upload?

Tags: php, images, uploads

I've been trying to resize an image client-side before uploading (see [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/167661/how-to-resize-image-on-client-side-before-upload)). I'm now trying to resize server-side before uploading.

I think `wp_handle_upload_prefilter` is the filter I should be using for this. Here's my attempt so far which isn't working:

```
function my_resize_before_upload( $file ) {
    $upload = wp_upload_bits( $file['name'], null, file_get_contents( $file['tmp_name'] ) );
    $image = wp_get_image_editor( $upload['file'] );
    if ( ! is_wp_error( $image ) ) {
        $image->resize( 80, 80 );
        $image->save( $upload['file'] );
    }
    return $file;
}
add_filter( 'wp_handle_upload_prefilter', 'my_resize_before_upload' );
```

How can I resize an image server-side *before* uploading?

Refs:

- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_upload_bits
- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_image_editor
- http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_handle_upload_prefilter

Comment: The server has no access to the file before it has been uploaded. This is impossible.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Not what I wanted to hear but now I know I can move on to explore alternatives. Thanks again